# How to run an Application as another user?

Tags: gnome, permissions, sudo

I use krusader for file management stuff. the problem is that apache's `DocumentRoot` should be under `chown www-data:www-data /path/to/www`. so using krusader (which is run under my account) I've not write access to `/path/to/www` while I really need. I don't know how other developers can continue doing things with such a restriction!

I wondered if I could run krusader as `www-data` then I will be able to easily play with files. but using `su - www-data` asked me for `www-data`'s password!!

**So, how can I run an application (like krusader) as another user (like www-data) in Gnome?**

or is there any other solution for my case? (tough I'm really curious to know the answer!)

keep in mind that I know I can run it **as root**! but this will cause some permission problems when using `cp` and `mkdir`, you know.

**PS:** 
`sudo` and `gksudo` did not help:

```
$ gksudo -u -www-data krusader
No protocol specified
krusader: cannot connect to X server :0.0
```

**Final Note:**
according the best answer, i did `chmod u+w /path/to/www` and my problem solved. but i still has not been succeeded in opening krusader as another user!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rethinking about this question (I hope to have understood your problem right, but correct me if I'm wrong), I found an another solution and I think you don't need to run the application as www-data nor to play with permissions. You said that:

> Apache's DocumentRoot should be under
>   chown www-data:www-data /path/to/www

but actually, this isn't fully true: Apache's `DocumentRoot` must be readable by `www-data`, but not necessarily owned by it. By default, in Ubuntu Desktop, all files and directories you create are readable by everybody, so you can set your DocumentRoot to a directory inside your home folder, for example:

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/my-project/my-document-root
```

Comment: thanks! it just worked. and your explanation of why this would work, was very helpful. as this solved my problem but i'm still curious to know how can i open krusader as another user. other solutions just did not work.

Answer (score 8):

```
xhost +SI:localuser:uname
gksudo -u uname -l "firefox"
xhost -SI:localuser:uname
```

Where uname = the name of impersonated user. Seen there:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10399617

Works on my maverick box, there's no sound in the forked skype and ~/.profile.d is not executed as it might.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running this from the menu system you'll want to use `alacarte` (System > Preferences > Main Menu) and change the entry for krusader and add in front of it: `gksudo -u www-data` which should produce something like:

`gksudo -u www-data krusader`

This will launch the administrative task prompt window which, according to the [GKSudo Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/gksudo.1.html), is a

> GTK+ Frontend for su and sudo

Using just gksudo without the `-u` switch will run the command as root.

Comment: thanks, but it returns: No protocol specifiedkrusader: cannot connect to X server :0.0

Comment: before launch gksudo command, in terminal under your account run: `xhost +`

Answer (score 4):

Like Marco mentioned you can use `gksudo -u www-data <command>` to run commands as another user. I routinely use this to run commands as `gdm` and so far it has never asked me for anything other than my own password.

If you are using kde the equivalent is `kdesu -u www-data krusader`.I think, since krusader is a kde application, it might work better with `kdesu`. More details about kdesu [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kdesu).

I have used `gksudo` to run commands as other "human" users on the system and when I am prompted for password, I type in mine.

Comment: thanks, but result is as gksudo: No protocol specifiedkrusader: cannot connect to X server :0.0

Comment: Probably for krusader (a kde app), `kdesu` is a better choice. I have updated my answer. Can you try that ?

Answer (score 4):

To become www-data with your own password, use this:

```
$ sudo su www-data
[sudo] password for <your username>: [enter your password]
$ whoami
(you should see www-data here)
```

But, I don't think you'll be able to run GUI apps from there..

I usually just own everything in `/var/www`, but allow read access to everyone:

```
/var/www$ sudo chown -R [your-username]\:[your-group] *
/var/www$ find . -type d -exec chmod a+rx {} \;
/var/www$ find . -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;
```

I hope that will ease your pain :)

Comment: as you guessed i couldn't run GUI apps from there. it sayed `No protocol specified
krusader: cannot connect to X server :0.0`

Comment: Is the second solution not an option for you? You data does not *have* to be owned by www-data, although I guess it's preferred.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to run the following at the terminal:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:<user-to-run-as>
```

Then you can do:

```
sudo su - <user-to-run-as>
```

And lastly, run your app:

```
krusader
```

That should do it, just be sure to replace `<user-to-run-as>` with your username of course.

Answer (score 0):

Both 'gksu' and 'kdesu' are graphical frontends for 'sudo', which is the tool you should use when you're in a text-only environment. The 'gksu' and 'kdesu' tools require you to be in a graphical mode, that explains the "cannot connect to X server" errors.

if you want to execute a console command as a different user you use the command 'sudo -u username command'.

Comment: thanks, i run that and it says something like `[1] 12100` that seems to be the process id; but nothing i see in action.

Answer (score 0):

Running a graphical application under www-data gives you several problems. A thing you can do is adding yourself to the www-data group, so you'll be able to change all the files you need:

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```

*Note: probably, you'll need to log out from the session for the change to take effect.*

If, after this command, you are still unable to change some files, just ensure that you have write permission on them:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/file
chmod g+w /var/www/file
```

Comment: however it isn't a solution for the general problem but it seems to work for my case; i'll give it a try and report

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Anton S. Kraievoy I used similar solution, which works for me. In the user, which using Krusader I added a new user to xhhost:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:username
```

Than kindly login:

```
su - username
```

Than krusader starts properly as a new instance in a new user:

```
krusader
```

Notice, that a new configuration will be created in ~/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc.