# how to run firefox as a different user?

Tags: xorg, firefox, users, environment-variables, browser

how do I determine whether [this](https://gist.github.com/kasunbg/5502cb630429819d07b5dc0cfa26813c) is starting `firefox` literally as a [different](https://askubuntu.com/q/70325/847449) user:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo su - foo
[sudo] password for nicholas: 
foo@mordor:~$ 
foo@mordor:~$ whoami
foo
foo@mordor:~$ pwd
/home/foo
foo@mordor:~$ 
foo@mordor:~$ firefox
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
foo@mordor:~$ 
foo@mordor:~$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
foo@mordor:~$ 
foo@mordor:~$ firefox
^C
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Terminated
foo@mordor:~$
```

in all [possible](https://superuser.com/q/1281604/977796) ways?

system info:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Answer (score 2):

Try  `sudo -u <username> <command>`, sudo preserves the environment variables like DISPLAY.

```bsh
$ xhost +SI:localuser:foo
localuser:foo being added to access control list
$ sudo -u foo firefox
```

Comment: localuser being who is currently logged into the GUI?  I'll read the fine manual.  thx.